# In RMarkdown, how to retrieve values from model output and put them in formatted LaTex?

Tags: r, latex, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

As an example, I'm running several survival models, each one has a different set of covariates.

#### First model

```
> coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
> summary(coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma, data = first.data, 
    method = "breslow")

  n= 49, number of events= 46 
   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
tr.ma 0.09520   1.09988  0.03906 2.437   0.0148 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

      exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
tr.ma       1.1     0.9092     1.019     1.187

Concordance= 0.694  (se = 0.058 )
Rsquare= 0.109   (max possible= 0.997 )
Likelihood ratio test= 5.68  on 1 df,   p=0.01718
Wald test            = 5.94  on 1 df,   p=0.0148
Score (logrank) test = 5.93  on 1 df,   p=0.01485
```

#### Second model

```
> coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma + contag_per, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
> summary(coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ tr.ma + contag_per, data = first.data, 
    method = "breslow")

  n= 49, number of events= 46 
   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)

               coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
tr.ma       0.09801   1.10297  0.04231  2.317 0.020518 *  
contag_per -1.97309   0.13903  0.51683 -3.818 0.000135 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

           exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
tr.ma          1.103     0.9066   1.01521    1.1983
contag_per     0.139     7.1929   0.05049    0.3828

Concordance= 0.752  (se = 0.058 )
Rsquare= 0.348   (max possible= 0.997 )
Likelihood ratio test= 20.98  on 2 df,   p=2.78e-05
Wald test            = 19.33  on 2 df,   p=6.357e-05
Score (logrank) test = 20.73  on 2 df,   p=3.147e-05
```

#### The problem

I want to get `exp(coef), Pr(>|z|)` from the output of each model and gather them into a table formatted in LaTex to make a concise report. Something like:

```
Model   covariates   exp(coef)   p-value
----------------------------------------
1       tr.ma        1.099       0.0148
2       tr.ma        1.103       0.0205
        contag_per   0.139       0.00013
...
```

It would be fantastic if I can automate that, since I have about 25 models, and having to manually retrieving and entering the numbers in a table would be quite inconvenient and error-prone. Thanks.

Comment: Check out awesome [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) package together with `kable` or `xtable` packages

Comment: @thecatalyst those packages are awesome! Is there a way to pull out ```exp(coef)``` from the output of ```coxph```? ```tidy``` pulls out the coefficients but not the hazard ratios :(

Comment: I guess I could work around that by compute it myself but was wondering if there's a way to do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your model. Maybe you can head to [Github](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues) page and ask there?

Comment: `tidy.coxph` has an `exponentiate` argument that will convert the coefficients to hazard ratios for you.